# React: Using arrow function to pass a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In one of my component I am using something like:

```
<PhotoList update_photo={() => this.update_photo()} />
```

Here I am passing a function as a props which updates a photo to the state..

and In my photo list component I have list of photos where I am updating the photo like:

```
<div className="single-photo" onClick={() => this.props.update_photo(photo)}>
```

Here it is passing `undefined` instead of photo.. buth when I use it in general way like `<PhotoList update_photo={this.update_photo.bind(this)} />` and `<div className="single-photo" onClick={this.props.update_photo.bind(this, photo)}>` it works

What is the difference and why is the first method not working ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without knowing how `this.update_photo()` is defined, but I'm guessing the problem is that the function you are passing in takes no argument, but you are trying to pass in an argument from the child.

So perhaps try wiring up the argument like this:

```
<PhotoList update_photo={(photo) => this.update_photo(photo)} />
```

Then `this.update_photo` should be able to set state based on the argument passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see how the `update_photo()` method is defined, but I suspect it has something to do with the fact [arrow functions don't bind their own this value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).  If you're using an arrow function as a method, [this will be undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods).